# How to Post JSON Data to server in phonegap

Tags: json, cordova

hi  i write in this code but i get Error like UNdefined how we can resolve this issue if any one know this answer plz let me know

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "application/json", url:"some url",

    data :{familyVoterId:'0',boothId:'0',voterId:'59136604',previousEnrollmentNumber:'29422415',casteId:'62',street:'hamlet',voterRelationId:'8',cadrePrevYear:'',relativeName:'DESSAPPA',previousRollesList:[{fromDateStr:'2012-10-24',cadreRoleId:'1',cadreCommitteeId:'1',cadreCommitteeLevelId:'1',toDateStr:"2013-10-24"}],partyMemberSinceStr:"2001-10-24",uniqueKey:"10d11073-a8b1-4764-bf2f-e2c0a269e9cd",nameType:"Voter",panchayatId:"0",age:28,surveyTimeStr:"2014-10-24 15:05:15",gender:"M",relationTypeId:8,bloodGroupId:3,dobStr:"1968-02-02",nomineeGender:"1",photoType:"VOTER",voterCardNumber:"UXN0862806",longititude:"78.413",aadheerNo:"987654321",candidateAadherNo:"12345678910",educationId:"2",nomineeAge:"21",previousParicaptedElectionsList:[{"electionTypeId":17,candidateId:"30126",constituencyId:"461"}],voterName:"RAMAKRISHNA",occupationId:"1",houseNo:"3-60",cadreFamilyDetails:[],createdUserId:"152",refNo:"TR-T-9999-12985",constituencyId:"282",latitude:"17.4278",nomineeName:"nominee",mobileNumber:"9999999999"},

    success: function(data)
    {

        alert("success");
    },

    error: function(msg)
    {
        alert(msg.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, in addition, the reason it is failing in the first place is because you need to do a cross-domain post. In  order to do this correctly through jQuery, you need to use the following options:

```
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your error. In Chrome if you click inspect element and then select the Console tab you can see the error message :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/DeleteME/pyMail/some%20url.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

As mentioned before you need to specify the data type as jsonp if your are posting to another domain.

Example:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", contentType:"application/jsonp; charset=utf-8", dataType: "application/json", url:"http://www.google.com",

    data :{familyVoterId:'0',boothId:'0',voterId:'59136604',previousEnrollmentNumber:'29422415',casteId:'62',street:'hamlet',voterRelationId:'8',cadrePrevYear:'',relativeName:'DESSAPPA',previousRollesList:[{fromDateStr:'2012-10-24',cadreRoleId:'1',cadreCommitteeId:'1',cadreCommitteeLevelId:'1',toDateStr:"2013-10-24"}],partyMemberSinceStr:"2001-10-24",uniqueKey:"10d11073-a8b1-4764-bf2f-e2c0a269e9cd",nameType:"Voter",panchayatId:"0",age:28,surveyTimeStr:"2014-10-24 15:05:15",gender:"M",relationTypeId:8,bloodGroupId:3,dobStr:"1968-02-02",nomineeGender:"1",photoType:"VOTER",voterCardNumber:"UXN0862806",longititude:"78.413",aadheerNo:"987654321",candidateAadherNo:"12345678910",educationId:"2",nomineeAge:"21",previousParicaptedElectionsList:[{"electionTypeId":17,candidateId:"30126",constituencyId:"461"}],voterName:"RAMAKRISHNA",occupationId:"1",houseNo:"3-60",cadreFamilyDetails:[],createdUserId:"152",refNo:"TR-T-9999-12985",constituencyId:"282",latitude:"17.4278",nomineeName:"nominee",mobileNumber:"9999999999"},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data)
    {

        alert("success");
    },

    error: function(msg)
    {
        alert(msg.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Message is not a property of the XHR object msg in your error callback function. That is why it shows undefined in your alert box. You can try to alert msg.statusText and see the status text.

Please check the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
(The jqXHR Object section)